# Help with set theory question about binary relations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations

On my assignment I was asked the question:

**Determine, with reason, if the binary relation is reflexive, symmetric, antisymmetric, or transitive.**

**Let X be any set containing at least three distinct elements a, b, c ∈ X. Let S be the
relation on P(X) such that (A, B) ∈ S when A ∩ B = {a}.**

I was wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction here as I don't even know where to begin. Where do the A and B come from? If S is the relation on P(X) then does it mean that (A,B) is only in the relation if its intersection returns only the element {a}? I can't seem to wrap my head around this question, any help would be appreciated. Thank you all for taking the time to read this.

Comment: $A,B\in \mathcal P(X)$, i.e. they are subsets of $X$. Like in the standard way we set-theortically define relations, $S$ is a relation on $\mathcal P(X)$ if and only if $S\subseteq \mathcal P(X)\times\mathcal P(X)$. Typically, we do not say that the intersection *returns* something; we say it *is* someting, but it seems true by the way the problem is worded that $(A,B)$ is in the realtion $S$ if and only if the intersection of $A$ and $B$ is the singleton $\{a\}$.

Comment: It is a carelessly posed question, and heads should roll. You are not paying your teachers to confuse you. S is a relation between subsets of X. The question should have said "Let S be the relation between members A, B of P(X) [or between subsets A, B of X] such that..." etc. Just parachuting in a couple of capital letters is contemptible.

Answer (score 1):

That $S$ is a relation on $P(X)$ mean that $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $X$. So for any two sets $A,B\subseteq X$ we say the relation $S(A,B)$ hold, or in other words $(A,B)\in S$ if $A\cap B=\{a\}$. Some hints to look at the properties:

1. Reflexivity: R is reflexive if for each $A\subseteq X$ it hold that $(A,A)\in S$ i.e. $A\cap A = \{a\}$, does this hold?
2. Symetry: R is symetric if for each $A,B\subseteq X$, such that $(A,B)\in S$ it hold that $(B,A)\in S$. If you translate $(A,B)\in S$ to the definition of S, then does it hold?
3. Anti-symetry: If $A,B \subseteq X$ and both $(A,B),(B,A)\in S$ then $A=B$. If you translate  $(A,B),(B,A)\in S$ by the definition, then does this hold?
4. Transitivity: If $A,B,C\subseteq X$ and $(A,B),(B,C)\in S$ then $(A,C)\in S$. Does this hold?